# How to use sailsjs generated session in phonegap html front page file

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, sails.js, ejs

Here, this my html code

```
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="socketApp"  ng-controller="NewsController">


<script id="users" type="text/template">


</script>
<script>
  onload = function(){
    var users = document.getElementById('users').innerHTML;
    // var names = ['loki', 'tobi', 'jane'];

    var html = ejs.render("<ul><li><%= session.User.name %></li></ul>", { });
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
  }
</script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
                io.sails.url = 'http://192.168.1.4:1337/';
    </script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.3.js"></script-->
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="js/socket.io.js"></script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ejs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

from the above code

```
var html = ejs.render("<ul><li><%= session.User.name %></li></ul>", { });
```

Here, i want to get sails server created session object in my cordova front end view. i tried many times , but i have't get session name. I'm very new to cordova . So , Please help me .

Comment: what does your sails.js controller code look like? Where do you actually set the User property on your session? Are you using passport.js? Because its probably session.user in that case.

Comment: i'm not actually using passport.js , i'm using sails session like this https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord

Comment: Session aren't great for mobile... I'd use JSON token instead. Will get rid of all your sessions/cros etc issues